# How can you make a program that simulates key-presses outside of itself? (python)

Tags: python, output, keypress, simulate

I am looking to make a program that can interact with applications on my computer through given commands that make the program simulate an actual user using a keyboard. How can I do this using python?

example, making a program that can type in Word, or play a game.

Comment: Take a look at `pyautogui` library

Comment: there are modules for this - ie. [pynput](https://pythonhosted.org/pynput/keyboard.html)